# Per branch user axis

Tags: git, jenkins

Say I have a user axis with tests on branch `master`:

- TESTS = test_1, test_2, test_3

now I creating another branch `feature` and add one more test: `test_4`.
Of course I want to test it on server. I don't want to modify a project on jenkins directly
since it became error prone and messy if I have a more branches. I'm looking for something similar
to [.travis.yml](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/blob/master/.travis.yml#L22) config file.

#### Update

Currently I'm using [matrix-project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project) jenkins plugin. This plugin allow me to set the "User Defined Axis" TESTS like: `test_1`, `test_2`, `test_3` but for **all** project in a whole (i.e. Jenkins ->
 MyProject -> Configure). Now I want to modify that axis only for one `feature` branch (I want to add one more value to axis: `test_4`). I'm looking for plugin that allow me to have per branch configuration (like [.travis.yml](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/blob/master/.travis.yml#L22), that I've already mentioned).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the Jenkins part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [job-dsl](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) plugin to rebuild the project. This plugin now [supports matrix jobs directly](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-reference#matrixjob)

What you would need is a separate job with a (groovy) job-dsl step to rebuild your matrix. If you use a template job then all existing configuration can reside there. Personally, I like to keep it all in the job-dsl step as the logic can be under version control.

```
def branches = ['a','b','c']

job(type: Matrix) {
    name ('existingJob')
    using ('myTemplateJob')
    axes {
        label('label', branches)

    }
}
```

I would use [JsonSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) to load the git branches

---

EDIT
I put this script together to demonstrate which builds an axis of the (3) branches in the job-dsl repo

```
def gitURL = new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/branches")
def branches = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(gitURL.newReader())
def names = []

branches.each{ names << it.name }

job(type: Matrix) {
  name 'git-matrix'
  description 'Matrix Job of my git repo'
  axes{
    text('branch', names )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, it's a nice plugin, +1. But I thinks it's an overkill for such a trivial task (one more project, now I need to learn a new language?). I know that travis ci using jenkins under the hood so I thought that I simply can't find the plugin with "in source config" feature (kind of an obvious solution). But looks like travis is more than just a "jenkins wrapper")) The closest thing that I've found for now is a literate plugin, see my answer.

Comment: Looks like this feature is still not implemented in literate plugin so I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution that I've found is the [literate plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Literate+Plugin).

For instance, branch `master`:

```
# Build
    echo "This is the master branch"
```

and if you create a branch `feature-1`, you can change the message:

```
# Build
    echo "this is a feature-1 branch"
```

But unfortunatelly AFAIK there is no such thing as user-defined custom variables.

#### Update

This feature is [planned](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/OOG81xvW73k).
Nice!

Answer (score 1):

The [recipe builder](https://github.com/manahl/recipebuilder) plugin lets you add a `.jenkins.yml` file, much like you would with Jenkins.